# BibTeX: How to have different separators for different entry types

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have to manually adapt a bibstyle and, for some reasons, I need to have periods as separators in books and commas in articles. As far as I understand the standard way of defining the separator is in the `output.nonnull` command.

Is there a reasonable way of having periods in book entries and commas for articles?

In other words, should I change the code of `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}` to contain some kind of an if clause to check whether the entry type is `book` or would it be more elegant to change the code of `FUNCTION {book}`?

**Edit**: More concrete is it bad or good practice to have the code

```
{ type$ "book" =
  { add.period$ write$ }
  { ", " * write$ }
if$
```

inside the `output.nonnull` function?